# Calculate time difference in format of hh:mm:ss.ms

Tags: bash

## General

#### Calculation example

```
variable_2    -  variable_1    =  result  
40:00:10.000  -  20:00:05.000  =  20:00:05.000
```

#### Other:

- not limited to 24h
- `variable_2` is always *bigger* than `variable_1`

---

## Working Code

Based on the answer here is the now working code.

#### What it does

The posted code below calculates as in the example above the time difference between two variables (`VARIABLE_1` and `VARIABLE_2`) with time formatting *hh:mm:ss.ms* and saves the calculation in the variable `RESULT` in the same format (*hh:mm:ss.ms*).

```
VARIABLE_1_IN_MS=$( VARIABLE_1 | awk -F'[:]|[.]' '{print $1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + $2 * 60 * 1000 + $3 * 1000 + $4}' )

VARIABLE_2_IN_MS=$( VARIABLE_2 | awk -F'[:]|[.]' '{print $1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + $2 * 60 * 1000 + $3 * 1000 + $4}' )

DIFFERENCE_IN_MS=$(( VARIABLE_2_IN_MS - VARIABLE_1_IN_MS ))

RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS=$DIFFERENCE_IN_MS

#Calculate *hours* in difference
HOURS_IN_MS=$(( RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS - RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS % (60*60*1000) ))
HOURS=$(( HOURS_IN_MS / (60*60*1000) ))
RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS=$(( RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS - HOURS_IN_MS ))

#Calculate *minutes* in difference
MINUTES_IN_MS=$(( RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS - RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS % (60*1000) ))
MINUTES=$(( MINUTES_IN_MS / (60*1000) ))
RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS=$(( RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS - MINUTES_IN_MS ))

#Calculate *seconds* in difference
SECONDS_IN_MS=$(( RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS - RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS % (1000) ))
SECONDS=$(( SECONDS_IN_MS / 1000))
RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS=$(( RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS - SECONDS_IN_MS ))

#Calculate *milliseconds* in difference
MILLISECONDS=$RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS

RESULT="$HOURS:$MINUTES:$SECONDS.$MILLISECONDS"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VARIABLE_1_IN_MS=$(echo "$VARIABLE_1" | awk -F':|.' '{print $1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + $2 * 60 * 1000 + $3 * 1000 + $4}' )
VARIABLE_2_IN_MS=$(echo "$VARIABLE_2" | awk -F':|.' '{print $1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + $2 * 60 * 1000 + $3 * 1000 + $4}' )
```

To pass the variable values to awk, use an echo command and add `$`'s. Quotes aren't, strictly speaking, necessary, but it's a good idea in general to quote any variable expansions to prevent whitespace and wildcard characters from being misinterpreted.

```
DIFFERENCE_IN_MS=$(( VARIABLE_2_IN_MS - VARIABLE_1_IN_MS ))
```

It should be noted that it's okay to omit `$`'s from variable references inside of `$((...))`, but that's one of the few contexts where that's the case. In normal usage, you must have `$`'s. Such as the following assignment:

```
RESIDUAL_DIFFERENCE_IN_MS=$DIFFERENCE_IN_MS
```